# Factorisation involving four terms (grouping two and two)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The expression $\frac{1}{4}(m+1)[m(m^2+m+2)+4(m^2+2m+2)]$ can be re-written as $\frac{1}{4}(m+1)[m(m^2+m+2)+2(2m^2+4m+4)]$ which can be further re-written, when the portion inside square brackets are fully expanded, as 
$\frac{1}{4}(m+1)(m^3+5m^2+10m+8)$. The intermediate step seems unnecessary but it is the crux of my question.

It is known that $(m+2)$ is a factor of $(m^3+5m^2+10m+8)$, so after using long division, the full expression can again be re-factorised as $\frac{1}{4}(m+1)(m+2)(m^2+3m+4)$.

However, why was I unable to obtain this simply by factorisation at the initial stage?

Using a simple example,

$ax+bx-3a-3b$ can be factorised as $x(a+b)-3(a+b)=(a+b)(x-3)$

Going back to the main question, since it is verified that $(m+2)$ is a factor of $(m^3+5m^2+10m+8)$ = $[m(m^2+m+2)+2(2m^2+4m+4)]$, and since $m$ and $2$ were already factorised out in their respective brackets, why wasn't I able to obtain an expression $(m+2)(a^2+b+c)$ directly?

$(m^2+m+2)\not= (2m^2+4m+4)$ but it should have been equal because $(m+2)$ was already pulled out!

I am really puzzled by this because it seems to contradict the concepts of factorisation involving four terms (the simple example I gave). It doesn't make sense - what am I missing?

Comment: The fact that there is addition involved is what you are not seeing.  Any number can be split into an infinite pair of values that are separated by that quantity.  The numbers making up the pair do not need to involve any factors of the original number.  The most simple example is $0$, which is $1-1$, $2-2$ etc.Another is $4$, which is $1+3$, $7-3$, $11-7$ etc.

Comment: Why should $(m^2+m+2)=(2 m^2+4 m+4)$?
You make it seem like if given $5(3)+2(17)$, then $(5+2)$ can be factored out -- giving what, exactly?  and $3$ must equal $17$?
$(5+2)$ does go in evenly, resulting in $7$ -- which cannot be seen anywhere in the initial expression.

Comment: $ax+bx-3a-3b$ can be factorised as $x(a+b)-3(a+b)=(a+b)(x-3)$

@danpost I had thought it was of the above form.